# Spatial index in Azure Mobile Services and Xamarin Azure component

Tags: azure, xamarin, spatial-index

Is it possible to add a spatial index to Windows Azure Mobile Services?

I added a free Mobile Service free 20mb database, then a table, then a geography type column.

I couldnt add an index to geography column using the 'management portal.'  But I connecting remotely using sql server management studio express i managed to write a TSQL to apply a spatial index.  It said it succeeded but I couldnt confirm it as the portal doesnt reflect it.

I'm now thinking

1) is it possible to add spatial index to azure sql databases? 
2) how do I add the geography type to my Xamarin project for easy read/write using azure component?

// update

I found a 'set index' button on azure dashboard when viewing the table columns but it threw an error:

```
Column 'Location' in table 'table.place' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index or statistics
```

Does this mean Azure database dont support spatial indices?

Answer (score 1):

Spatial indexes are supported in SQL Database (with some restrictions), see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff759530.aspx

That said, spatial types are not directly supported with Window Azure Mobile Services; however, you can use converter classes to support additional types that are not handled by the client SDKS.  See [Carlos Figueira's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/08/30/supporting-arbitrary-types-in-azure-mobile-services-managed-client-simple-types.aspx) for details.